# Problems scraping pages with JavaScript function in python

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm stuck with a python problem, look.

I have to scrap a page that has JS functions, but that's not the real problem, the real problem is that the information I need is provided by the function.. So I need to run the function to make sure it'll build the HTML code that I need, and then work on it to get what I want..

Just to make sure i'm clear, the JS function build the HTML code, but when I scrap it, it doesn't get HTML buid, it just return the JS function...

I am using mechanize and beautifulSoup for the scraping process.. does anyone know what do I have to do to emulate the JS function to get the HTML code that I need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would figure out how the JS function builds the HTML. Mechanize doesn't execute JS, so it won't be too helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need a scrapping framework that supports javascript. [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is one of them and I got good results using along with BeautifulSoup.

You may want to check [PyVirtualDisplay](https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay) if you are going to use [Selenium with Mozilla Firefox](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/python-headless-selenium-webdriver.html).